# PHP including nested templates refuses to render master template on some pages

Tags: php

I have a PHP site that is using this piece of code to render content pages inside the master template.

```
function render($template, $vars = array(), $supertemplates = array()) {
  if (is_array($vars)) extract($vars);  // Extract the vars to local namespace
  else $content = $vars;
  ob_start();                    // Start output buffering
  include($template.'.tpl.php'); // Include the file
  $content = ob_get_contents();  // Get the content of the buffer
  ob_end_clean();                // End buffering and discard
  foreach ($supertemplates as $supertemplate)
  $content = render($supertemplate, array('content' => $content));
  return $content;               // Return the content
}
```

The application itself is a huge file index.php (in the root of the site) with a router that takes an argument and then executes the appropriate function.

This is the list function

```
function list() {
    //Get some data from the database ($data)
    print render('templates/_list', array('data' => $data), array('templates/master'));
    exit;
}
```

The list template then renders another template inside itself.
But currently the only html sent to the browser, is the list template, the mastertemplate is not even sent to the browser. I have seen this a few times before, but it would usually go away after a browser refresh.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?
This only happens on some templates, not all, but i have not been able to find out why that is, as i don't belive there are any major differences in what the pages that work, and the one that dont' does.

Comment: I fixed the issue by setting my DEBUG variable to false. It seems that firephp may be the cause. If DEBUG was set to true, it would log some data to the client, i belive through the headers. I guess i shouldnt log data while inside the render method. Does this sound like the cause?

Comment: Yeah, scratch that. Still an issue.